# SQL - Aggregate same column through different criteria

Tags: mysql, sql

Say I have a table **Orders** that looks like this,

```
|country| customer_id | order_id |
| CA    | 5           |     3    |
| CA    | 5           |     4    |
| CA    | 6           |     5    |
| CA    | 6           |     6    |
| US    | 2           |     7    |
| US    | 7           |     8    |
| US    | 7           |     9    |
| US    | 7           |    10    |
| US    | 2           |    11    |
```

and I want to write a query to populate a table as so,

```
| country | customers_w_2_orders | customers_w_2_plus_orders |
| CA      | 2                    | 0                         |
| US      | 1                    | 1                         |
```

where it aggregates number of customers with 2 orders and number of customers with 3 orders by country.

Here's what I did and it did not give the result I want..

```
SELECT country, count(*) as cnt1, count(*) as cnt2 
FROM Orders 
GROUP BY country 
HAVING cnt1=2 AND cnt2>2;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> declare @orders table (country char(2), customer_id int, order_id int);
> insert into @orders values
> ('CA', 5, 3),
> ('CA', 5, 4),
> ('CA', 6, 5),
> ('CA', 6, 6),
> ('US', 2, 7),
> ('US', 7, 8),
> ('US', 7, 9),
> ('US', 7, 10),
> ('US', 2, 11);
>
> select country,
>        sum(case when num_orders <= 2 then 1 else 0 end) as cust_w_2_orders,
>        sum(case when num_orders > 2 then 1 else 0 end) as cust_2_plus_orders
> from (
>       select country, customer_id, count(*) num_orders
>       from   @orders
>       group by country, customer_id
>      ) x
> group by country;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> country | cust_w_2_orders | cust_2_plus_orders
> :------ | --------------: | -----------------:
> CA      |               2 |                  0
> US      |               1 |                  1
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=06b38ea78ca363605e585bae155c27dd)*

Comment: Will not get the format OP wants. You will produce a sparse table.

Comment: The query you provided finished in 0.5 ms which beats other answers. Thanks!

Comment: I"m glad to be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

First construct a table that contains every customer and the # of orders they have per country where each row is `country, customer_id, number_of_orders`

Now you can count how often `number_of_orders` is 2 or greater than 2 by grouping on the derived table

```
select country, sum(num_orders = 2), sum(num_orders > 2)
from (
    select country, customer_id, count(*) as num_orders
    from Orders
    group by country, customer_id
) t group by country
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT country,
       (select count(distinct(customer_id)) from Orders o where o.country = Orders.country and (select count(*) from Orders o2 where o2.country = orders.country and o2.customer_id = o.customer_id) = 2) as customers_w_2_orders,
       (select count(distinct(customer_id)) from Orders o where o.country = Orders.country and (select count(*) from Orders o2 where o2.country = orders.country and o2.customer_id = o.customer_id) > 2) as customers_w_2_plus_orders
  FROM Orders 
 GROUP BY country;
```